# Python Polars - conditional join on value between other columns

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I have a Polars DataFrame that looks like this:

```
┌────────────┬───────┐
│ date       ┆ value │
│ ---        ┆ ---   │
│ str        ┆ i64   │
╞════════════╪═══════╡
│ 2022-01-01 ┆ 3     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-01-02 ┆ 7     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-01-03 ┆ 12    │
└────────────┴───────┘
```

I have another DataFrame that looks like this:

```
┌──────────┬───────┬───────┐
│ category ┆ lower ┆ upper │
│ ---      ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str      ┆ i64   ┆ i64   │
╞══════════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ A        ┆ 0     ┆ 5     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B        ┆ 5     ┆ 10    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ C        ┆ 10    ┆ 15    │
└──────────┴───────┴───────┘
```

I want to join these two DataFrames so that the first DataFrame has a new column "category" where each row is categorized based on which category it falls between in the second DataFrame. The final DF should look something like this:

```
┌────────────┬───────┬──────────┐
│ date       ┆ value ┆ category │
│ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---      │
│ str        ┆ i64   ┆ str      │
╞════════════╪═══════╪══════════╡
│ 2022-01-01 ┆ 3     ┆ A        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-01-02 ┆ 7     ┆ B        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-01-03 ┆ 12    ┆ C        │
└────────────┴───────┴──────────┘
```

Is there a way to do this efficiently using Polars? What about with an unlimited upper bound on category C?

Answer (score 1):

If you have many categories in your second dataframe, you can "convert" it to SQL CASE expression:

```py
cond = df_pl2.select(
    pl.format(
        "WHEN value >= {} AND value < {} THEN '{}'",
        pl.col("lower"),
        pl.col("upper"),
        pl.col("category"),
    ).alias("cond")
)
cond = "\n".join(cond["cond"]) + " ELSE 'Not Found'"
```

The `cond` now contains:

```
WHEN value >= 0 AND value < 5 THEN 'A'
WHEN value >= 5 AND value < 10 THEN 'B'
WHEN value >= 10 AND value < 15 THEN 'C' ELSE 'Not Found'
```

---

Then use Polars `SQLContext()`:

```py
ctxt = pl.SQLContext()
ctxt.register("df_pl", df_pl.lazy())  # <-- `df_pl` is your first dataframe

print(
    ctxt.execute(
        f"""\
    SELECT date, value,
    CASE
        {cond}
    END AS category
    FROM df_pl
""",
        eager=True,
    )
)
```

Prints:

```
┌────────────┬───────┬──────────┐
│ date       ┆ value ┆ category │
│ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---      │
│ str        ┆ i64   ┆ str      │
╞════════════╪═══════╪══════════╡
│ 2022-01-01 ┆ 3     ┆ A        │
│ 2022-01-02 ┆ 7     ┆ B        │
│ 2022-01-03 ┆ 12    ┆ C        │
└────────────┴───────┴──────────┘
```

---

If you want unlimited upper bound just update the last condition in the CASE statement, for example `cond = cond.replace("AND value < 15", "")`

Answer (score 1):

[`join_asof`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.join_asof.html#polars.DataFrame.join_asof) is best for this "nearest key" type of problem. There are forward/backward join strategies:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({'value': [3, 7, 12]}).set_sorted('value')
df2 = pl.DataFrame({'category': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'lower': [0, 5, 10], 'upper': [5, 10, 15]}).set_sorted(['lower', 'upper'])

df.join_asof(df2, left_on='value', right_on='lower', strategy='backward')
# equivalent alternate way, although the above is better for "unlimited upper bound"
df.join_asof(df2, left_on='value', right_on='upper', strategy='forward')
```

```py
shape: (3, 4)
┌───────┬──────────┬───────┬───────┐
│ value ┆ category ┆ lower ┆ upper │
│ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ i64   ┆ str      ┆ i64   ┆ i64   │
╞═══════╪══════════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ 3     ┆ A        ┆ 0     ┆ 5     │
│ 7     ┆ B        ┆ 5     ┆ 10    │
│ 12    ┆ C        ┆ 10    ┆ 15    │
└───────┴──────────┴───────┴───────┘
```

Alternatively, you could do a [`cut`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.cut.html#polars.Expr.cut) expression instead of any type of join:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({'value' : [3, 7, 12, 99]})
df2 = pl.DataFrame({'lower' : [0, 5, 10], 'upper' : [5, 10, 15]})

df.with_columns(
    category=pl.col('value').cut(
        df2.get_column('upper'), labels=['A', 'B', 'C', 'unlimited']
    )
)
```

```py
shape: (4, 2)
┌───────┬───────────┐
│ value ┆ category  │
│ ---   ┆ ---       │
│ i64   ┆ cat       │
╞═══════╪═══════════╡
│ 3     ┆ A         │
│ 7     ┆ B         │
│ 12    ┆ C         │
│ 99    ┆ unlimited │
└───────┴───────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

As the intervals don't overlap, it looks like `.search_sorted()` could also be an option:

```
date = pl.from_repr("""
┌────────────┬───────┐
│ date       ┆ value │
│ ---        ┆ ---   │
│ str        ┆ i64   │
╞════════════╪═══════╡
│ 2022-01-01 ┆ 3     │
│ 2022-01-02 ┆ 7     │
│ 2022-01-03 ┆ 12    │
└────────────┴───────┘
""")

category = pl.from_repr("""
┌──────────┬───────┬───────┐
│ category ┆ lower ┆ upper │
│ ---      ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str      ┆ i64   ┆ f64   │
╞══════════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ A        ┆ 0     ┆ 5     │
│ B        ┆ 5     ┆ 10    │
│ C        ┆ 10    ┆ inf   │
└──────────┴───────┴───────┘
""")

(date.lazy()
     .with_context(category.lazy())
     .with_columns(
        pl.col("category").take(pl.col("upper").search_sorted("value"))
     )
    .collect()
)
```

```
┌────────────┬───────┬──────────┐
│ date       ┆ value ┆ category │
│ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---      │
│ str        ┆ i64   ┆ str      │
╞════════════╪═══════╪══════════╡
│ 2022-01-01 ┆ 3     ┆ A        │
│ 2022-01-02 ┆ 7     ┆ B        │
│ 2022-01-03 ┆ 12    ┆ C        │
└────────────┴───────┴──────────┘
```